# Why don't any of these BST methods work?

Tags: java, class, testing, methods, binary-tree

Ok so in my binary search tree I made a bunch of methods but I'm currently testing 2 of them. One of them inserts an item into the tree:

```
public void insert(String word) { //calls the insert method
    root=insertItem(root, word);
}


protected TreeNode insertItem(TreeNode r, String word) { //inserts an item x into the tree
    if(r==null){
        r = new TreeNode(new WordRefs(word));
        r.left = null;
        r.right = null;
    }
    else if(word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) < 0){
        r.left = insertItem(r.left, word);
    } else if (word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) > 0){
        r.left = insertItem(r.right, word);
    }
    return r;
}
```

The other one deletes an item:

```
public void delete(String word) { //calls the delete method
    root = deleteItem(root, word);
}


protected TreeNode deleteItem(TreeNode r, String word) { //deletes an item x from the BST 
    if (r == null){
        return r;
    }
    if(word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) < 0){
        r.left = deleteItem(r.left, word);
    } else if (word.compareTo(r.item.getWord()) > 0){
        r.right = deleteItem(r.right, word);
    } else if(r.left != null && r.right != null){
        return deleteItem(r, word);
        }
    return r;
}
```

And here is the code that tests these methods

```
public static void main(String args[]) { //the tests are in the main method
    BSTRefBased t;
    AbstractBinaryTree tt;
    int i;
    boolean result;
    String message;

    message = "Test 1: inserting 'word1' -- "; //tests the insert method first
    t = new BSTRefBased();
    try {
        t.insert("word1");
        result = t.getRootItem().getWord().equals("word1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    System.out.println(message + (result ? "passed" : "FAILED"));

    message = "Test 2: inserting 'word1', 'word2', 'word3' -- ";
    t = new BSTRefBased();
    try {
        t.insert("word1");
        t.insert("word2");
        t.insert("word3");
        result = t.getRootItem().getWord().equals("word1");
        tt = t.detachLeftSubtree();
        result &= tt.getRootItem().getWord().equals("word2");
        tt = t.detachRightSubtree();
        result &= tt.getRootItem().getWord().equals("word3");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    System.out.println(message + (result ? "passed" : "FAILED"));

    message = "Test 3: deleting 'word1' -- "; //it then tests the delete method (note I keep getting failed for this one)
    t = new BSTRefBased();
    try {
        t.delete("word1");
        result = t.getRootItem().getWord().equals(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    System.out.println(message + (result ? "passed" : "FAILED"));

            message = "Test 4: deleting 'word2' 'word3' -- ";
    t = new BSTRefBased();
    try {
        t.delete("word2");
        t.delete("word3");
        result = t.getRootItem().getWord().equals(null);
        tt = t.detachLeftSubtree();
        result &= tt.getRootItem().getWord().equals(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    System.out.println(message + (result ? "passed" : "FAILED"));
}
```

For my output it says test 1 passed but test 2, 3, and 4 all failed. So why did test 2, 3, and 4 fail? here's what I want the delete method to look like :

```
delete(treeNode ,searchitem)
targetNode = search(treeNode ,searchItem)
if targetNode is null
return

P = parent node of target Node

if targetNode has no children
update ref in P that leads to targetNode
return

if targetNode has only one child C update ref in P that leads 
to targetNode by overwriting that ref with C 
(either left- or right-ref in P)
return

M = targetNode's inorder successor (i.e., left-most in-order 
successor in targetNode's right subtree)
m = item in M
copy m into targetNode's item field 
delete (treeNode, M)
return
```

Comment: I think you should help us out and at least tell us if it's the insert or delete. That should be easy to verify. You also invoke other methods you didn't give that could be wrong I suppose.

Comment: That's the thing. The first test tests it when it's inserting a single item and it passes. The second test tests to see if it can insert multiple items and it fails. So for the insert method it works if it inserts a single item but then fails when it inserts multiple items. As for the delete method that one fails if it deletes one item or several.

Comment: you are inserting "word1" twice and in your insert method you dont handle "= 0" only ">" and "<" there is an "= 0" case that "word1" inserting again would have to be handled

Comment: usual to go to the left node would be "<= 0"

Comment: But how do I handle it. If it's < or > 0 then it either goes to the right or the left but what do I do if it equals 0?

Comment: for the 3rd and 4th your making  t = new BSTRefBased(); before each test and there is nothing to delete in each new instance

Comment: @JRowan, isn't that just neglecting to insert duplicates. If it's not < or > then it's =, then we just return the node that already holds that string.

Comment: @Chief yeah your right

Comment: So I tried saying if word == 0 then just return r. I then tried to have it also return inserttem but no matter what I do it still fails. So how am I supposed to insert the item if it equals 0?

Comment: "word2" is > then "word1" so it would fall into the rightsubtree

Comment: as Cheif said how you had it was fine for = 0 it would just return the node that already had the string in it

Comment: So how exactly am I supposed to handle two strings being the same? I've tried returning the node but it keeps saying that it failed.

Comment: just how your code is on the post it is fine, maybe where you are checking  tt = t.detachLeftSubtree();
        result &= tt.getRootItem().getWord().equals("word2"); word2 is > then word1 shouldnt you use   tt = t.detachRightSubtree(); for that maybe your booleans are mixed up

Comment: Personally, I think you could test this much easier without mangling the tree in the process. Insert some items, print the tree, delete one or more, print the tree, do variations until you covered all insertion and deletion points. IOW, I'm not convinced it's not the test.

Comment: Ok so the reason why adding all those 3 words don't work isn't because I'm adding the same word because I changed word1 to word12 and the test still fails so there much be something wrong with the insert method.

Comment: word12 is still greater than word1 its in the right subtree, all the elements that you add are in a right subtree of right subtrees, and your delete is way off, you should look at this theres different cases when you delete from a BST http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion

Comment: That delete methods looks alot different from what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is [see original post for delete method pseudo code]. So how would I implement that pseudo code in java?

Answer (score 1):

Your tests (except for Test 1) look screwy to me.

Test 2 asserts that the root of the BST is `"word1"`, while the left subtree is `"word2"` and the right subtree is `"word3"`.  This is... unlikely.

Since both `"word2"` and `"word3"` come *after* `"word1"`, your insertions *should* produce a linked-list, with `"word1"` at the root, `"word2"` as its right child (and a `null` left child), and then `"word3"` as the right child of `"word2"`.  This will not pass Test 2.  (I say "should", because a separate bug makes the tree even weirder... see later in this answer.)

In short: unless your BST has a re-balancing step somewhere that you haven't told us about, Test 2 is dead wrong.

Tests 3 and 4 will *never* pass, because they raise a `NullPointerException` every time --- but you can't see it, because it's caught and replaced with a `false` value.  Both tests attempt to remove one or more words from an *empty tree* --- they don't add those words first.  Then, they call `getRootItem`, which will always return the `null` root of a brand-new BST.  Finally, they kill themselves trying to call the `getWord` method on that `null` reference.

That doesn't mean your `BSTRefBased` is off the hook, though.  I noticed a few bugs in it, too:

Your `insertItem` method always adds to the `r.left` child, never `r.right` (a typo).  This will mangle your BST by accidentally severing the legitimate left subtree... sometimes.

Finally, I'm not sure `deleteItem` will ever actually delete an item.  The null, less-than, and greater-than cases look OK, but then...

```
// The "found the word" case...
} else if(r.left != null && r.right != null){
    return deleteItem(r, word);
}
```

So, if this `TreeNode` has two children, it will call `deleteItem` with *exactly the same arguments*, which should recourse until you run out of stack space and crash.

Cases in which there is only one child or zero children aren't handled at all --- `r` (the current `TreeNode`, which should have been deleted) is instead returned, and the "deleted" word remains in the tree.